# What could I do to optimize rendering time of image with tkinter?

Tags: pi-3, python, image, performance, tkinter

I've been working on a project using Python 2.7 and TKinter which needs to render 25 images per second based on GPIO inputs.

I have working code on my Ubuntu laptop, which is able to render an image every 0.015 seconds which is more than enough. When I put this on my Raspberry Pi 3, an image is rendered in 0.15 seconds which is **way** to much, the limit being 0.04 seconds.
The fact is that nor my CPU or RAM is used at 100%, so I'm wondering where the limitation could come from, any ideas?

For your information here are a few extra inputs:

- The images are ~ 100 - 150 kb
- The format of images is gif so I don't need to use the pillow library
- I'm only using tkinter
- I've tried using the memory card and a USB drive to read the images to see if the limitation was coming from the transfer rate of the microSD card

Some of my code to give you a better idea:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1280, height = 720)
tkImage = tk.PhotoImage(file=img) #img is the path to the image
canvasImage = canvas.create_image(640, 360, image=tkImage) #show first image
dicimg = {}

def update_image(event):
    global i, max, canvas, canvasImage
    start = time.time()
    if i < max:
        i = i + 2
    else:
        i = 0
    img = image_spot + 'frame{0:05d}.gif'.format(i)
    tkImage = tk.PhotoImage(file=img)
    dicimg['img1'] = tkImage
    canvas.itemconfig(canvasImage, image = tkImage)
    canvas.update()
    print('uploaded in: '+ str(time.time()-start))

while i < max:
    update_image(None)

root.bind("<space>", update_image)
tk.mainloop()
```

As suggested by James Kent I've profiled my code and this is the result after updating the images 50 times:

```
Thu Apr 12 14:35:09 2018    profiler

     1932 function calls (1922 primitive calls) in 7.316 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.010    0.010    7.316    7.316 test_tkinter_gif_auto.py:1(<module>)
      206    7.039    0.034    7.039    0.034 {built-in method call}
       50    0.007    0.000    6.948    0.139 test_tkinter_gif_auto.py:20(update_image)
       51    0.001    0.000    3.127    0.061 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:3370(__init__)
       51    0.005    0.000    3.125    0.061 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:3307(__init__)
       50    0.001    0.000    2.927    0.059 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:2405(itemconfigure)
       51    0.002    0.000    2.926    0.057 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:1315(_configure)
       50    0.001    0.000    0.875    0.018 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:1025(update)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.219    0.219 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:1803(__init__)
        1    0.218    0.218    0.218    0.218 {_tkinter.create}
       49    0.001    0.000    0.072    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:3332(__del__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.055    0.055 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:2321(create_image)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.055    0.055 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:2304(_create)
        1    0.019    0.019    0.021    0.021 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:31(<module>)
       54    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py:1165(_options)
```

If I understand this correctly what takes most of the time is the `_init_` from the Tkinter PhotoImage and an other `_init_` (where??), followed by the `itemconfigure` and the `update`. Any idea how to optimize?

Comment: have you tried profiling your code first? this should help you work out which bit is slow, only then can we look at how to speed it up. https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual

Comment: also, a comment about the CPU, cPython as written above (not using multiprocess) can only utilize a single core, as the pi3 has 4 cores the highest use you would see with a single python script maxing out its core would be 25% (with a bit of variation for system processes)

Comment: @JamesKent: I haven't tried profiling my code, I will go read the information on the link you gave me.

Comment: @JamesKent: The fact Python only uses one core is interesting, because When I launch this on an Intel core i7 all cores seem to work together. Is it possible this is due to Raspbian running on Pi 3 and Ubuntu on the Intel core i7?

Comment: it shouldn't make any difference what operating system you use, if it's C python (the ref implementation) then it implements something called the GIL or global interpreter lock, this means that even with threading only one thread is active at a time, as a thread can only run on a single cpu core at a time it is by definition limited to one core, other python implementations do not have the GIL, and in these cases multi thread/core is possible. the only thing that could mess with this is native code does not need the GIL, so in some cases (usually I/O) multi core operation may happen

Comment: @JamesKent: I've updated my question with the cProfile output. Also, if I follow your reasoning, this means all is based on the CPU clock speed? This would work out as I have tested this on mutiple computers and computers with clocks under 2.5 Ghz started to be to slow. Pi 3 had it's CPU at ~33% while running this test.

Comment: the first init (3370) is the PhotoImage init, with the second being the Image init. the only thing I can suggest would be to try it with pillow to see if that improves the loading time. but it looks to me like the limitation is inside the tk libs not the python libs, so there isn't much you can do about it except try another image lib like PIL, but i suspect this may be slower, but no way of knowing without benchmarking it

Comment: @JamesKent: Tested with Pillow as first Iteration and it was slower. I've seen I could use a library to multi-thread. I'll try that out and give an update here as soon as it's done. Also, any chance to find out if the time for the _init_ being so long is due to CPU, disk access time or something else?

Comment: as stated before, multi thread won't help you unless the limitation is I/O bound, is there any reason you can't pre load all the images and then display the relevant one in a loop? that eliminates all the I/O, and instance creating/destroying from the inside of the loop

Comment: @JamesKent: I've tried to do this that way but it takes up way to much memory. We have a total of 35'000 images to load.

Comment: can i ask what exactly you are trying to achieve? is it to show the gpio pin states in something approaching realtime? if so it may prove more effective to use pillow and generate the images at runtime using the ImageDraw module, this way you'd save all the creating and destroying of objects and the disk I/O

Comment: @JamesKent: We are trying to show 25 images per second based on the GPIO input that comes from a gear. The said gear has about 60 cogs, each cog asks for an image change. We can't use a video file as we need to go forward and backwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75984/discussion-between-james-kent-and-no-or-yes).